# How to get data into html in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use angular to send data from parent to child component. In my parent component I use a onclick event to send data to my child component.

In my child component user-profile.ts i have this:

```
@Input('user')
  set user(user: any) {
  
  }
```

I know that the component recieved the data because if i console.log(user) it shows the data. However it doesnt see the data in the html. In the html of this file i have this

```
<h1>
  {{ user.name }}
</h1>
```

But i then get the error: "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". What logic do i put into my .ts file to fix this?

Comment: Can you show your .ts file code?

Comment: Parent or child component?

Comment: It may be you don't get user fast enough. If you want to avoid error, use `user?.name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below in your user-profile.ts

```
@Input() user: any; // or use your User type
```

and in your child component html file you can keep your change. To avoid undefined errors you can use. In your html.

```
{{user?.name}}
```

Comment: This fixed it instantly. I had setup my "@Input()" wrong. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't written the get statement

```
private _user; //Always defined the type instead using the any 
@Input('user')
set user(value: any) {
    this._user = value;
}

get user() {
  return this._user;
}
```

and also check null handle in user property, if data delayed.

```
    //HTML
   <h1>
   {{ user?.name }}
   </h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I already picked a correct answer but I think this answer would also solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you had pass the correct object and it not undefined.
Or the best way is have it own default value.

Comment: Hi, I think it's a common question, you will spend time on google I am sure you can easily found.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use `@Input() prop: type;` in the child component. You can of course also send a object instead of a string

```
component.ts
@Input() user: string;

component.html
<h1>{{ user }}</h1>

parent.html
<child-component [user]="username"></child-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a profile.component.ts and use the following in that respective file

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private service:Services)
  {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userName: ['', Validators.required],
     //other info
    });
  }
ngOnInit() : void{
   this.getDetail();
}

getDetail() {
  this.service.getProfileDetail().subscribe(
    (res: any) => {
      this.userDetail = {
        userName: res.result.userName,
       };
    }
```